# Zabbix frontend 2.2.2 cannot display host map

Tags: zabbix

I moved my zabbix fronted on a separate server. Today there is a problem when I try to open the map hostnames. The user has full rights to all hosts. After a moment map appeared, anybody have some idea what's wrong ?

Regards

[image]

Comment: This looks like an already known bug. See [ZBX-7838](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7838).

Comment: @asaveljevs You could probably make a complete answer of that.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an already known bug with packaging, which was fixed in Zabbix 2.2.3 under [ZBX-7838](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-7838).